# How to play a SFML game on another computer

Tags: c++, sfml

I've been searching a lot for this, but can't seem to find an answer who really does the job. I want to able to play my game, using C++ with [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), on other computers than my own. I've tried to simply copy the .exe file and the images over, but I just get errors about missing .dll files when I do that. I've seen other people on the SFML forums do this, so it must be possible somehow... I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Do you mean you want to deploy the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) library on other computers so your game can run there?

Comment: Well, so other people can play my game on their own computers without installing MS VC++.

Comment: It will usually tell you which DLLs are missing. Find those and put them in the same directory as the EXE.

Comment: Ironically enough that worked. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share my SFML game with others without errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602222/how-can-i-share-my-sfml-game-with-others-without-errors)

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on deploying an SFML application, statically building your project is recommended. This requires also statically building SFML. It takes a little time to setup, but all dependencies will be included in your executable making your application much more reliable and easier to install. This process is not to be confused with statically linking to SFML, which you will still need to do once you've statically build SFML.

You will have to clone the [SFML repository](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) and use [CMake to generate your visual studio project](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php) that will then let you build SFML statically with /MTd for debug and /MT for release. These options can be found in `Project Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library`.