# how to make my executable not rely on sfml dll files [c++] [minGW] [g++]

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, sfml

Perhaps I can "create" these necessary files by having them linked to the exe, and store them in a temp folder when the program launches, and if that's possible how please? I've tried messing around with compiler options but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you even try? https://www.google.com/search?q=distributing++sfml+dlls

Comment: "Create these necessary files by having them linked to the exe" sounds like *static linking*.

Comment: Otherwise, if you create an *installer* it can collect all DLL's you need and install them together with the executable. There are many tools to create installers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I share my SFML game with others without errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602222/how-can-i-share-my-sfml-game-with-others-without-errors)

Comment: So what compiler option do I need to static link, I've tried putting `-static` and messing around with the options from https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link-static.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the required DLL files in the same folder as the EXE file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order your executable to not rely on DLL files, you should link them statically. SFML gives you that option by using their "sfml-xxx-s-d.lib" (for Debug) and "sfml-xxx-s.lib" (for Release) libraries, as stated in the documentation.

> If you want to get rid of these DLLs and have SFML directly integrated
> into your executable, you must link to the static version. Static SFML
> libraries have the "-s" suffix: "sfml-xxx-s-d.lib" for Debug, and
> "sfml-xxx-s.lib" for Release. In this case, you'll also need to define
> the SFML_STATIC macro in the preprocessor options of your project.

*NOTE: "xxx" stands for the name of the file you are trying to include into your project*

Full documentation on how to set up SFML in VisualStudio: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php

Hope this answered your question! :)

Comment: Oh wow thank you, I got everything to work, sheesh I'm dumb. I had sfml installed directly on minGW, which is not what you needed to do it seems, and after that I simply included all the necessary libs into the compiler settings and it worked. Cheers!